# Set a child array state object from props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a react application using hooks but I'm getting a weird behavior on my code, I'm not going to put all my code here but I will give you an example what it's going on.

```
const Child = props => {
   const {data} = props;
   const [myData, setMyData] = useState(data);

  const items => myData.map( r => <li> r </li> );

   return ( <ul> { items } </ul> );
}

const Parent = () => {

   return (<div> 
             <Child data={ [1, 2, 3] } 
           </div> );
}
```

I am making changes to the array that the Parent component sends to the Child component. 
When I add a new element to the array, the Child component re-render so MyData is equals to the array ( this makes sense because the Child components is re-render by the props change ).
If I delete an element from the array the Child component is re-render  but myData doesn't change and the element I deleted from the array is still there in myData.

Why the useState sets the array to myData when I add elements to the array but when I delete elements it seems like this doesn't work,even though the Child component is re-render.

I know it seems a little dumb, you can ask me, why you don't just use the props value on the Child component instead of a state value, well the idea is on the Child component there is a search control so I can make some kind of searching over MyData and not over the props value ( but maybe there is another way ).

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code here please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is how you're using props.

When `Child` renders, it gets `props.data` from `Parent`. It then copies `data` to its component state as the variable `myData`.

From here on, changes to `props` can trigger the `Child` to re-render, but `myData` won't be redefined again via `useState`. That happens only once.

If you're writing code that does hot-reloading (you save the file and the application reloads in the browser), it might seem like changing the props sent to `Child` updates `myData`, but that's not happening in a production environment.

My suggestion: if you're going to fork props into the state of `Child`, think of props as an initial value, and not something that `Parent` can update.

The React docs explain why this is an anti-pattern:

> The problem is that it’s both unnecessary (you can use `this.props.color` directly instead), and creates bugs (updates to the color prop won’t be reflected in the state).
>
> Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop updates.

[React constructor docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and the lesson too, I will change this.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMyData(data)
},[data])
```

your data will be load to state only once. but you can handle changes on data by parent component with useEffect, useEffect will updates when data will updated

there is full code

```
const Child = props => {
   const {data} = props;
   const [myData, setMyData] = useState(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMyData(data)
    },[data])

  const items => myData.map( r => <li> r </li> );

   return ( <ul> { items } </ul> );
}

const Parent = () => {

   return (<div> 
             <Child data={ [1, 2, 3] } 
           </div> );
}
```

you can read about [React use effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)